# AFNetworking: success and failure blocks not called!! (POST to mysql backend)

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I am still trying to get a hang of objective-c and AFNetworking. I am doing a POST (through UI button) on mysql backend which returns a json response. I can see the download progress, but my success and failure blocks are never called. Code snippet below. I only see 1 and 4 printed out.

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest = [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:kAPIPath parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {

     NSLog(@"Success in calling");
     }];

     AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: apiRequest];
     NSLog(@"1");
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //success!
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        NSLog(@"2");
        completionBlock(responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //failure :(
        NSLog(@"3");
        completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
    }];
    });
     NSLog(@"4");

    [operation start];

[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^( NSUInteger bytesRead , long long totalBytesRead , long long totalBytesExpectedToRead )
     {
         NSLog(@"%lld of %lld", totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead);
     }
     ];
```

Comment: Do you ever see a download progress where bytesRead and ExpectedToRead are equal?

Comment: Yes, I do. I also tested with http://www.google.com/m and it's always the same. The blocks are never called.

Comment: Why do you initialize an AFHTTPRequestOperation with an AFJSONRequestOperation?

Comment: still doesn't work. The blocks should eventually be called on main thread right?

Comment: Wrong. The blocks will *not* be called on the main thread. Calling them on the main thread would be very bad design. They are completely asynchronous, and you cannot depend on which tread they will be called on.

Comment: true, but it should still be printing out the (response and 2) or 3 (for failure)?

Comment: yes, the blocks just shouldn't be called on the main thread.

Comment: Is this exact copy/paste? It looks like you're creating the AFJSONRequestOperation in the `multipartFormRequest:` `constructingBodyWithBlock` block.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/307) AFNetworking issue.